# Make Front Row act more like it did on Tiger (OS X 10.4)

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, itunes, osx-leopard, front-row

I used to use Front Row *all* the time on Tiger.  When I walked away from the computer, I could hit the "menu" button on my Mac's remote to get a full screen interface for iTunes that I could easily read from across the room.  When I came back, I could just hit a key on the keyboard and Front Row would get out of the way so I could get back to work.  I still have the **full screen** interface on Snow Leopard (and Leopard), but the iTunes integration seems crippled.  On Tiger, Front Row would pop up with the **currently playing** track in iTunes, rather than stopping whatever was playing and making me go through a series of menus to start the music back up.  (On the backend, I think this change happened because Front Row was mostly an AppleScript wrapper for iTunes in pre-Leopard versions.)

I'd *really* like to have the old functionality back -- without it, Front Row seems practically useless.  I'm fine with using the old version itself, if there's a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Found a relevant thread on [MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=475634), but the extracted `Front Row.app` doesn't seem to do anything (visible) on Snow Leopard.

**Update 2:** My bad -- it *does* work!  For some reason, I thought it would work without copying to `/System/Library/CoreServices/`, but that's not the case.  As they mention, make sure to back up the newer version that you overwrite if you try this.  I'm on a MacBook2,1 OS X 10.6.1, just for others' reference.